# Microsoft alternative to Auth0

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, auth0

Does Microsoft have any services that is similar to Auth0? Something that does not require me to host my entire application on Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to host anything on Microsoft, You can use its Federation services for authentication and host you application on AWS.

Microsoft provides Azure AD and Azure B2c for federation, depending on your use case you can pick one of it. B2C is used for customer facing applications and AD can be used for internal(Within the company) federation.

You can start by reading some of their docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview